# Color xml in android studio

Tags: android

```
 <component name="libraryTable">
<library name="Gradle: com.android.support:drawerlayout-28.0.0-alpha1">
    <CLASSES>
        <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawerlayou
```

what is missing in the above code as Android Studio show this error :

Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

Comment: i thing you need to close tags

Comment: how to close tag in this code?? which tag is unclose ? can you tell me?

Comment: root tag not close

Comment: This is a bug in Android Studio... It's nothing to do with tags... E.g that's clearly not the color xml file

Comment: Not sure about the bug, if this is the real file, it's clearly bad structured (but yes, this is no color.xml)

Answer (score -1):

its about ">" at the end of your code 
generally this error shows you that there is something wrong in the start or at the end of your xlm code 
for example the code below is correct

if you write it like

or

xxx>

you will see this error
something wrong with the range of the start and end tags.